# Object.keys() not working in ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, html-select, ng-options

I am trying to create a dropdown list using ng-options:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="m1">
  <head>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="c1">
    <div>
      Sort1
      <select ng-model="sortKey1">
        <option value="bookId">By Id</option>
        <option value="bookTitle">By Title</option>
        <option value="cost">By Cost</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      Sort2
      <select ng-model="sortKey2" ng-options="x for x in Object.keys(books[0])">
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      Sort3
      <select ng-model="sortKey3" ng-options="x for x in bookKeys">
      </select>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var m1 = angular.module("m1", []);

    m1.controller('c1',function($scope)
    {
      $scope.books = [
      {
          "bookId": 101,
          "bookTitle": "Angular JS",
          "cost":375,
      },
      {
          "bookId": 102,
          "bookTitle": "Instant AngularJS Starter",
          "cost":150,
      },
      {
          "bookId": 103,
          "bookTitle": "Ng-Book: The Complete Book on AngularJS",
          "cost":4657,
      }];

      console.log(Object.keys($scope.books[0]));
      $scope.bookKeys = Object.keys($scope.books[0]);
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

I am trying to get the dropdown values from an object's keys by calling `Object.keys()` on an object and then using the resultant array in `ng-options`.

I am trying to create the effect of *case 1*. My attempt at *case 2* is not working, however a similar thing implemented in *case 3* is working.

Can anybody tell the reason why *case 2* is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**
As indicated in Zen's answer, the reason `Object.keys()` does not work in `ng-repeat` is due to the context in which it is evaluated (that being the context of `$scope`).

Angular has this functionality built in in the form of `(key, val)`. Sometimes the support for native javascript functions within an Angular express is limited and in this instance Angular probably doesn't understand `Object.keys()` as the source for `ng-options`. Change the `<select>` in your case 2 to:

```
<select ng-model="sortKey2" ng-options="key as key for (key,val) in books[0]">
```

Working example:

```js
    var m1 = angular.module("m1", []);

    m1.controller('c1', function($scope) {
      $scope.books = [{
        "bookId": 101,
        "bookTitle": "Angular JS",
        "topic": "AngularJS",
        "author": "Green",
        "cost": 375,
      }, {
        "bookId": 102,
        "bookTitle": "Instant AngularJS Starter",
        "topic": "AngularJS",
        "author": "Dan Menard",
        "cost": 150,
      }, {
        "bookId": 103,
        "bookTitle": "Ng-Book: The Complete Book on AngularJS",
        "topic": "AngularJS",
        "author": "Ari Lerner",
        "cost": 4657,
      }];

      console.log(Object.keys($scope.books[0]));
      $scope.bookKeys = Object.keys($scope.books[0]);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="m1" ng-controller="c1">
  <div>
    Sort1
    <select ng-model="sortKey1">
      <option value="bookId">By Id</option>
      <option value="bookTitle">By Title</option>
      <option value="topic">By Topic</option>
      <option value="author">By Author</option>
      <option value="cost">By Cost</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    Sort2
    <select ng-model="sortKey2" ng-options="key as key for (key,val) in books[0]">
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    Sort3
    <select ng-model="sortKey3" ng-options="x for x in bookKeys">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: (*applied to answer*) If you want the value of a select option to not become the value of the object (for eg. `101`, `AngularJS` etc.), you can write `<select ng-model="sortKey2" ng-options="key as key for (key,val) in books[0]">`

Comment: You will find that the Angular support for javascript functions within an expression is sometimes limited. This appears to be one of those instances.

Comment: Can you add this to the answer? Also, I've added something to your answer; just verify if it's correct, cause I'm not an Angular expert.

Comment: Gah...can't believe I wrote it as `key for...` instead of `key as key for...`. I have updated my answer to include this since it is the proper form. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All binding expressions are evaluated relative to `$scope`. So when you write `for x in Object.keys(books[0])`, angular runs it as `for( x in $scope.Object.keys([books[0]) )`. Apparently, `Object` is not defined in the scope chains. If you want it to work, you can copy all global variables to the `$rootScope`, that doesn't seem to be a bad habit.

```
m1.run([`$rootScope`, function($rootScope){
    var keys  = Object.getOwnPropertyNames( window );
    keys.forEach( key => {
        $rootScope[key] = window[key];
    });
}])
```

Comment: Ah, good call. My assumption was that Angular didn't understand `Object.keys()`, but your explanation of the context in which it is evaluated makes much more sense. However, I don't think using `$rootScope` is a good solution, especially with the support of `key as key for (key, val) in ...`.